# How to paginate the PDF while using mpdf to generate PDF file from HTML

Tags: php, html, pdf, pagination

I'm using MPDF to generate PDF from HTML. It works perfectly fine while I made the HTML string and pass it to the PDF generator. But I find out it's not enough. How could I change the current page to the next page. I mean in HTML string. For example, if you're making some PDF for the delivery forms on your website. You want to make every form start with a fresh new page. But the MPDF will auto paginate the HTML content which might cannot fit your need. How can I deal with this part? I'm getting confused. I try to read the source code,but the code is too much. And there's not enough comment inside. I hope there's some one who familiar with the MPDF lib. The version of MPDF which I'm using is v5.4 by the way.

Comment: you want to start from new page after adding some data to pdf??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even i had the problem of breaking the page in mpdf. For that you should use `addPage()` of mpdf or `<pagebreak />`

```
$mpdf->AddPage();
```

or

```
<pagebreak />
```

using either of the above, you can force page breaks in mpdf,
check [this](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=108) for more reference

Answer (score 0):

Unclear exactly what you need, but this might get you going.

If you have a multiple forms and you want those forms to be on their own pages, you have a couple possible solutions:

1. You could iterate over the `forms` and use `$mpdf->AddPage();` at the end of each `form`
2. If you have an entire string and the `forms` are all together, you could use the html tag `<pagebreak />` to signal a break where you'd like.

Reference the [docs](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=108) for further information, if needed. Hope it helps.

Comment: No problems, don't forget to mark as answer for future guests!